# Equivalence relations-Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Here is an equivalence relation R={ (x,y) | x-y is an integer}

My question is: what is the equivalence class of 1 for this equivalence relation?

Can say indicate the equivalence class of 1 as [(1)] = { (x,y), x-y=  }

I am confused about how to write the right hand side? can someone help me?

Comment: do you mind to explain?

Comment: Now, I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your equivalence relation is that $x$ is related to $y$ if $x-y \in \mathbb Z$. What numbers give integers if you subtract $1$ from them? The integers, since they are closed under subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence class of $1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.
Show that $x-1$ is an integer if and only if $x$ is an integer.